# javascript Dynamics 365 unable to save my field before refreshing

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm working on Dynamics CRM 365, trying to apply a logic using javascript on the opportunity form.

The need is to change a field's value and save the form before another treatment could refresh it.

```
var opportunityID= formContext.data.entity.getId();
           var fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>"+
                          "  <entity name='saft_bpf_isd_opportunities'>"+
                          "    <attribute name='businessprocessflowinstanceid' />"+
                          "    <attribute name='activestageid' />"+
                          "    <filter type='and'>"+
                          "      <condition attribute='bpf_opportunityid' operator='eq' uitype='opportunity' value='"+opportunityID+"' />"+
                          "    </filter>"+
                          "  </entity>"+
                          "</fetch>";

           Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("saft_bpf_isd_opportunities","fetchXml= " + fetchXml).then(
           function success(result) { 
              debugger;
              alert("existed value ==> "+formContext.getAttribute("saft_activestage").getValue());
              alert("new value ==> "+result.entities[0]._activestageid_value);
              formContext.getAttribute("saft_activestage").setValue(result.entities[0]._activestageid_value);
              formContext.data.save(70).then(function (result) {});

           },function(error) {
                console.log(error.message);
              }
           );               
        // the reatement refreshing the form  
        formContext.data.process.setActiveProcess(idProcess_ISD, function (result) {});
```

But when I apply this code, I can simlply display the value but not assign it to the field desired.

Comment: Can you move `formContext.data.process.setActive(...)` into the `Success` method?

Comment: @jasonscript Thank you for your response, it works half the time only when I clear the cache. is there no workaround for that please

Answer (score 0):

`Xrm.WebApi` methods are always Asynchronous, it returns a browser Promise object & return the result  in Async mode. Therefore when you want something to execute based on success callback result move it inside.

Same way `.then` helps you to put the code execution in sequence. Not sure how the cache clearing works randomly but made couple of changes. You can put breakpoints/debug to see it in action or just alert.

```
Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("saft_bpf_isd_opportunities","fetchXml= " + fetchXml).then(
           function success(result) { 
              debugger;
              alert("existed value ==> "+formContext.getAttribute("saft_activestage").getValue());
              alert("new value ==> "+result.entities[0]._activestageid_value);
              formContext.getAttribute("saft_activestage").setValue(result.entities[0]._activestageid_value);
              formContext.data.save(70).then(function (result) {
            alert("after save"); 
            formContext.data.process.setActiveProcess(idProcess_ISD, function (result) { alert("setActiveProcess completed"); });
         });

           },function(error) {
                console.log(error.message);
              }
           );
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, i can now understand the execution of the Xrm.WebApi methods. I've tried to apply the same logic using .then It doesn't work :/ I'll try to debug that later

Comment: it works only half the time, didn't find any logic explanation for that

Comment: @ELMASLOUHIHAMZA do you have auto-save enabled? Can you try this code in another entity form, vanilla crm instance to find out the root cause? What do you mean by work half the time - it works on some record & not in other record? Can you add some timeout in code & see if the delayed execution helps? If you put a debugger is it always hit or bypassing then?